# Sharepoint web.config deployment

Tags: web-config

I have sharepoint project which has own customized web.config file. In package I have customized config, but I need to apply those changes to second sharepoint server where are sources deployed.
Have anyone idea how to perform it?

Many Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to do changes to the web.config is to use a one-time timer job that runs when a feature is activated on the specific Web Application and uses SPJobLockTyp.None (so it runs on all machines in the farm).

And please, make sure to make a corresponding one-time timer job that removes the configurations when the feature is deactivated.